# how to disable geckofx debug logging

Tags: c#, geckofx

I am using the gecko web browser for a Windows form application.

I saw you could turn off debug logging using the following lines

```
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.DRIVER_USE_MARIONETTE, "true");
        System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "C:\\temp\\logs.txt");
```

but I get this error
"the type or a namespace name setproperty does not exist with the namespace "System"
I don't know if this is the right solution because they think it is more related to selenium web driver.

so in my trace file there is a lot of garbage from gecko, mainly
"GetChromeFlagsAttribute called"